# Why do home gateways host their own DNS servers?

Tags: networking, router, dns, dhcp

Every consumer-grade gateway I’ve seen hosts its own DNS server and tells DHCP clients to use it. I’ve gotten into the habit of overriding them with OpenDNS/Google/etc., since these DNS servers tend to stop working for no apparent reason.

My question is, what reasons could manufacturers have for including this “feature” that often doesn’t really work? My guesses:

- So users can register hostnames for machines on the LAN.
- Caching.

Neither of those seems compelling enough, but I’m not a networking professional so I might be missing something. It just seems like it’d make much more sense if the gateway told DHCP clients to use the same DNS servers the gateway uses.

Comment: Personally I've never seen them "stop working for no apparent reason". Most of them just run DNSMasq

Comment: I'll second @qasdfdsaq's comment wholeheartedly.

Comment: Same, i was just thinking what the issue was anytime that happened to me.  Generally flushing the DNS or rebooting the modem/router is the first thing I do, since you know, computers are perfect.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq: You're lucky. The ones I get tend to use something more homegrown, and the D-Links are outright awful. (Truncating to 512 bytes, mixing up sections... released in 2015!)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Home gateways originally added DNS proxy servers well before they added DNS content servers (the latter is the ability to define hostname to IP address mappings right on the gateway).

The reason they added the ability to act as DNS proxy servers was to keep DNS from breaking if the WAN interface gets renumbered. If your gateway's WAN interface gets dynamically told the list of public DNS server addresses to use (via DHCP, PPPoE, PPPoA, etc.), then that list could change at DHCP renewal time, or if the PPP[oE|oA] link gets renegotiated. If the old list of DNS servers is no longer valid/reachable on the new connection, there's no way to communicate that change to your LAN clients in a timely manner. DHCP provides no way for a server to immediately "push" configuration updates to clients. It has to wait until the clients need to renew their DHCP leases, which could be hours or days later, depending on how the DHCP server is configured.

So, by telling all the clients to send DNS queries to the gateway, the gateway can always make sure they get to the currently-correct DNS servers, regardless of how often the ISP changes that list.

Pitifully, there are lots of cheap/crappy/buggy consumer home gateways out there that don't do this right, so this feature that is supposed to make DNS more reliable actually does the opposite. It sounds like that's the experience you're most familiar with.

Comment: Ah, right! I thought about this but ignored it since I'm used to cable internet through Comcast, which tends not to change and I think uses the same DNS IPs everywhere. But yeah, sounds like there are many configurations where the gateway should be prepared for the ISP's DNS to change.

Answer (score 4):

Mostly, it is done so that DHCP clients can refer to other machines on their LAN by name instead of IP address. If you just pass the name or IP address of some external DNS server like Google or OpenDNS, you lose this functionality.

This loss of functionality can partly be compensated for by OS-specific services like SAMBA for Windows and Linux, or Bonjour for Mac. But a local DNS works equally well for all machines on a LAN.

The functionality is easily extensible to static-IP addresses like printers for instance, so that you really do not need to remember the IP address of anything on your net.

Also, the convenience of having a local DNS grows very fast with net size, and/or with the presence of other LANs connected to the gateway. For instance, I have a permanent OpenVPN connection between my home and my lab at my University, and the total number of users between the two exceeds one hundred, including my daughters' Xbox station.

Not compelling? Certainly. Inconvenient? Equally certainly not.

Comment: This, plus a lot of home gateways use "easy access" domain names for accessing the gateway's own web interface - often along the lines to "www.routerlogin.net" or "http://bthomehub.home" for example, which rely on local DNS server(s) to work.

Answer (score 0):

Routers tend to use internal DNS Servers for name resolution on the same network, because if you ping computer1 from computer2, only the router will know the correct IP.  (MariusMatutiae beat me to this one)

It will also act like every other DNS Server out there (including the public ones you use), and will start going to other DNS Servers until it finds a server that knows the IP Address and location.

That's also the same reason if you run a trace route on a domain, it talks to multiple servers before getting to the server that hosts the website.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the previous answer about DHCP/Dynamic DNS. This is important to some people (I use DNS internally all the time). So it makes sense to have this functionality as an option, making the router more valuable as a product.

It also provides DNS when the internet connection is down. Again, I need that, so I can still use my network during an outage.

I feel dns caching is a big advantage. It makes things very snappy. It's easy to implement, has low overhead and makes things faster. Why not use it?